# How to get nestjs websocket exception error in client side using react?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, socket.io, nestjs, nestjs-gateways

I am try to create a realtime project for practice. I use `nestjs` for backend and `react` for frontend. Here in `nestjs` I am suing websocket.

In `nestjs` I write this code

```
@SubscribeMessage("createMessage")
handleCreate(
    @MessageBody() messageInput: MessageInput
): WsResponse<string> {
    console.log(messageInput)
    if (messageInput.conversation !== 12) throw new WsException("Error occured from siam!");
    return { event: "createMessage", data: "Hello world" }
}
```

Here I throw an `WsException` when `conversation` not equal to `12`.

In frontend (`reactjs`) I emiting-

```
const MessageData = {
    conversation: 16
}
socket.emit("createMessage", MessageData)
```

Here I sent 16 as `conversation`. It should throw an error from backend.

How can I get that error from frontend. Actually my question is where I found that `WsException` error in react application. I have not find any idea about. can anybody help me about this case, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen on a specific event: `exception`.

Comment: That's mean event name is `exception`?

Comment: Definitely it is.

Comment: wow...that worked for me